# Max If Over an Array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `FormulaArray` that i am using to calculated the maximum value based on a single condition. The problem is the formula takes way too long to calculate and I am not sure how to do this calculation more efficiently. Does anyone know of a more efficient formula or VBA Function that will greatly increase the speed of this calculation? Here is the formula I have -

```
ws.Range("CD" & i).FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(I:I=I2,AR:AR))"
```

Thanks much!

Comment: don't do the whole column, define thee depth of I and AR

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!

Comment: Here is what I ended up with

Comment: ws.Range("CD" & i).FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(I2" & ":I" & lr & "=I" & i & ",AR2" & ":AR" & lr & "))"